# How to setup values for unit test for IEnvironmentVariableRetriever

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, xunit

I need to setup a mock with values for IEnvironmentVariableRetriever. Here is my class constructor

```
public LiabilityDataService(IEnvironmentVariableRetriever variableRetriever)
{
    this.liabilityAddress = variableRetriever.GetEnvironmentVariable("BASE_URL"); 
    this.cognitoAddress = variableRetriever.GetEnvironmentVariable("COGNITO_ADDRESS");
    this.Secret = variableRetriever.GetEnvironmentVariable("SECRET");
}
```

Here is my test,

```
    [Fact]
    public async Task GetResponse_WhenGetLiabilityDatasReturnedAsync_ShouldReturnData()
    {
        // Arrange
        var environmentVariableRetrieverMock = new Mock<IEnvironmentVariableRetriever>();

        var quotes = new[]
        {
            "Q00001"
        };
        var startDate = new DateTime(2020, 06, 20);
        var endDate = new DateTime(2020, 07, 03);

        var liabilityDataService = new LiabilityDataService(environmentVariableRetrieverMock.Object);

        // Act
        var response = await liabilityDataService .GetLiabilityData(quotes, startDate, endDate);

        // Assert
        response.Data.All(x => x.Value.Values.Count == 1).Should().BeTrue();
    }
```

The test fails of course in line `var response = await marketDataService.GetLiabilityData(quotes, startDate, endDate);`
I've tried to use

```
 environmentVariableRetrieverMock.SetupGet(x => x["BASE_URL"])
                .Returns("https://Liabilitydev.azurewebsites.net/api/liabilitydata");
```

but there is no properties to setup. Is there another way to set it up?

Many thanks

Comment: you have 16 questions in total and none of them have accepted answer. please review them and mark which of them helped you to resolve your issues

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup function invokations for your object instead. Setup steps should be taken according to how `LiabilityDataService` uses `IEnvironmentVariableRetriever`

```
var environmentVariableRetrieverMock = new Mock<IEnvironmentVariableRetriever>();
environmentVariableRetrieverMock
    .Setup(x => x.GetEnvironmentVariable("BASE_URL"))
    .Returns("your url");

environmentVariableRetrieverMock
    .Setup(x => x.GetEnvironmentVariable("COGNITO_ADDRESS"))
    .Returns("your address");

environmentVariableRetrieverMock
    .Setup(x => x.GetEnvironmentVariable("SECRET"))
    .Returns("your secret");
```